# Change row height of pinned columns ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

Is there a way I can change the row height for pinned columns.I know there is a **setRowHeight**
method, but how does it work on pinned columns

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the pinned row data in order to make it work. See this [section](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-height/#height-for-pinned-rows) here:

> **Height for Pinned Rows**
>
> Row height for pinned rows works exactly as for normal rows with one
> difference: it is not possible to dynamically change the height once
> set. However this is easily solved by just setting the pinned row data
> again which resets the row heights. Setting the data again is not a
> problem for pinned rows as it doesn't impact scroll position,
> filtering, sorting or group open / closed positions as it would with
> normal rows if the data was reset.